# Network Credential does not prompt when accessing shared folder with password protection ON - Windows 11

Tags: windows, networking, windows-11, file-sharing, shared-folders

My folder sharing only worked if it was set as accessible from private, work, and public networks with password protection off.

If I enabled password protection I never received a prompt to enter credentials. It only returned an error, access denied, with no prompt to enter the credentials.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP says they solved the credential issue by using passwords

Comment: Having my shared folder available to anyone is unacceptable since it is a laptop and I have to connect to many public access points. 

I have provided an answer for future troubleshooting since I haven't found any other solution to this problem.

Comment: This normally means that an erroneous credential in Credential Manager needs to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a Windows credential for the PC I was trying to access.

To add a Windows credential to your Windows vault:

1. Click Start, type **Credential Manager** and select the same from the list.
2. Click **Windows credential** on the right.
3. Click Add a Windows credential.
4. In the Internet or network address box, type the computer name on the network you want to access. (example: \\MY-LAPTOP)
5. In the **User name** and **Password** boxes, type the username and password you use for that computer or website, then click OK.

If you have changed a username in the past on the PC you're trying to access, your current username might not be valid. You might want to look under:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts -> Here you will see your original username that is used to access the PC.

(I changed my local user to a Microsft account but the username, used to enter the credentials is the old local username...)